Introductory books in Random Matrix Theory for Riemann zeta function
In many papers when studying Riemann zeta function (like Alternate Hypothesis, or pair correlation conjecture) I faced with terms like "gaussian unitary ensemble" or "random matrix theory". I would like to learn about this subject but any book I find has 500+ pages and unfortunately I have a limited time to learn. Is there any book concise but still introductory on GUE and RMT that specifically relevant to Riemann zeta function? Or otherwise, which chapters of those comprehensive books I need to study? Thanks
